# I'm getting null value from web element object in code below

Tags: java, selenium

I getting null value from web element object in code below.

Im currently getting a null pointer exception error.

```
WebElement element = null;
String locatorVal = "userId";
element = Constant.driver.findElement(By.id(locatorVal));
```

Comment: Did you initialize `driver`?

Comment: what is Constant here ?

Comment: We don't have enough info to answer

Answer (score 0):

probably you should change code as below. Or share more info

```
element = driver.findElement(By.id(locatorVal));
```